# What projections and input file parameters are supported by r.resamp.rst?

Tags: raster, grass-gis

I always get ERROR: Unable To Seek after I run `r.resamp.rst`

```
r.resamp.rst input=map30 ew_res=10m ns_res=10m elevation=map10
```

It actually starts to work but after it finish I get the error and no output.

Fresh install of Grass GIS 7

I'm suspecting this has something to do with invalid input files, and resolutions. 
So the question is:

**What projections and input file parameters are supported by r.resamp.rst?**

Comment: Have a look at the [r.resamp.rst](https://grass.osgeo.org/grass71/manuals/r.resamp.rst.html) manual of grass, it tells you exactly which parameters are supported.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My region settings and projections were not good, still don't know what I missed but it wokrs now.

Make sure your location and regions settings are correct.